# gst_init (&argc, &argv) crashes with gst_value_table was nullptr

Tags: c, gstreamer, gstreamer-1.0

I've downloaded gstreamer tutorial from its official website.
I'm trying to run its basic-tutorial-1 and it crashes immediately at first line itself:

```
gst_init (&argc, &argv);
```

Exception is:

```
Faulting module: gstreamer-1.0-0.dll
Exception thrown: read access violation.
**gst_value_table** was nullptr.
```

Can someone please suggest what might be wrong?

I've compiled in x64 using Visual Studio 2017 on Windows.

Looks like something is missing in installation sequence, unable to figure it out.

Comment: Apart from asking here, it would also be good to notify the author of the tutorial of this problem.

Comment: can you post minimal reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example ?